# My C++ App Crashes Only in Release Mode and Windows 7

Tags: c++, debugging, windows-7, crash, release

I'm very frustrated with my app crash in Release Mode on Windows 7.

In the main function, I removed everything:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {
    return (0);
}
```

But I do have a lot of directives, variables and functions defined outside of the main functions.

It only crashes in Release mode on Windows 7.
Debug mode on Windows 7 is okay;
Debug and Release modes on Windows XP are both okay.

Since I cannot debug, I don't what to do.

The error is:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00dc21ca in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x8496a9bb.
```

Assembly line:

```
00DC21CA  mov         eax,dword ptr [edx+0Ch]
```

This is so crazy, Please help.

Peter

P.S.: If I removed everything I defined outside the main, then it's okay.

P.S.:

```
char* AllocArgsMemory()
{
    return (char*)malloc(2); // works: return NULL
                             // So it seems the malloc has some problems
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should remove one thing at a time until it works, so you know what to blame. Or post the code.

Comment: wow. Now there is a good one. Do you include any libraries other than the standard ones? You may want to check if something is (somehow) hooking into the _main function which runs before main.

Comment: Also, check your constructors. Are constructors for global objects causing the crash(which would happen before main) ?

Comment: Put it on the .NET framework ;)

Comment: This may happen if your global (namespace-level) object depend on other object's initialization. Different compilers can initialize the objects in a different order, that's why you see different behavior on different platforms. You have to figure out what object causes the crash.

Comment: Why do you say you cannot debug? Because your app crashes during start up? Because its release mode? Visual Studio can start your application with the debugger attached even in release mode and it will break if it encounters an unhandled exception.

Answer (score 1):

Check all the pointers you are using. They way your app crashes shows that you are dereferencing a null pointer or outside of a pre-allocated memory range(e.g. array). This is probably due to an uninitalized pointer or too large a subscription index.

It does not crash in debug mode, because in debug mode, the debugger usually inits uninitalized memory with a predefined value, e.g. 0xcccccccc, which does not happen in release mode.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is a release binary, you should create a full symbol file (.pdb) so you can have a decent callstack when your issue occurs. 
To get it : start any debugger (WinDbg, Visual Studio, etc.), setup it to stop on access violation exception, start you process with it, it should break when the exception occurs and give you a callstack. 
Remember that a debugger can run anything that can be executed ; even if you don't have links to source code and local variable values, you may have other usefull informations.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like it may be some of the built settings/properties.  I don't have a lot to offer you (partially because the lack of information), but if its working in DEBUG mode in windows 7, like setting all the build settings/properties in RELEASE the same as DEBUG.  If it works, you know it is an issue with a build setting

Comment: More likely the settings on the DEBUG build hide the problem without fixing it -- the build setting is not actually the issue.